# Conv filter visualization in Keras: Why do some filters get stuck at loss==0 and how can I prevent that?

Tags: keras, filter, conv-neural-network, visualization

I am using this script from the Keras-Team to visualize conv filters of the VGG16 model:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/conv_filter_visualization.py

For most filters, this works. However, if I try to generate the image for filter 11 in layer "block5_conv1", the algorithm gives me no output, because "some filters get stuck to 0" (line 156 ff):

```
# some filters get stuck to 0, we can skip them
if loss_value <= K.epsilon():
    return None
```

This is the only thing I changed in the script (last line):

```
visualize_layer(vgg, "block5_conv1", output_dim=(112, 112), filter_range=(11, 12))
```

Running exactly the same code again a couple of times finally resulted in an image (I guess because the randomly generated starting image changed):

[image: Filter 11 in block5_conv1]

However, for many other filters, e.g. block5_conv3, filter 1, I had no luck:

```
visualize_layer(vgg, block5_conv3, output_dim=(112, 112), filter_range=(1, 2))
```

I also changed the output_dim, step, epochs, upscaling_steps, upscaling_factor but wasn't able to produce an image.

**So my question is: Is there a way, to generate a visualization of each filter reliably (based on the script provided)?**

Comment: I'd say this is a common issue with the neural networks - it is related to either too small amount of data, wrong weights initialization or lack of proper regularization

Comment: but all these points shouldn't be an issue with the VGG16 which was trained on the imagenet data (huge data set, correct weight init, proper regularization)

Comment: To me this sounds more like a research problem/question than a programming one.

Comment: My first attempt was to recreate the model without 'relu' because of it's zero zones. Curiously, other activations produce even more zero filters....

Comment: Curiosity: I never understood the point of getting gradients and losses for visualizing filters.... Not a complain, just an honest question: what is this code supposed to show?